# Removing floor from 3D surface plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to "remove the floor" from a 3D surface plot. For example, in this matplotlib demo code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=8, cstride=8, alpha=0.3)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=-100, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='x', offset=-40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='y', offset=40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim(-40, 40)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim(-40, 40)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim(-100, 100)
```

[image]

I am trying to just get the top half of the 3d surface, without the blue floor and the bottom hump. I'd like them **transparent**.

I've tried setting `vmin` appropriately, and even using a masked array but I still get the "floor" of color in my plots.

Note: My *real* situation is plotting a KDE generated on some data, on a grid of points and I dont want the entire bottom of my plot to be the same blue color.

Comment: What does "setting vmin appropriately" mean? I think it should be possible to set the unwanted values to a transparent color.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea can be to set the unwanted part to a transparent color, using a normalization of the colormap.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.colors

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)

norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(0,100)
cmap = cm.coolwarm
cmap.set_under((0,0,0,0), alpha=0.0)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=8, cstride=8,  norm=norm, cmap=cmap)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim(-40, 40)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim(-40, 40)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim(-100, 100)

plt.show()
```

[image]